# How can I solve django.db.utils.OperationalError when I try to migrate data when I run my docker compose up command?

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

I am currently working on a project to deploy a django app using docker compose but I keep getting a `django.db.utils.OperationalError` when I try to migrate data when I run the `docker compose up` command.

This is the full error I am getting;

```
 => ERROR [6/7] RUN python3 manage.py makemigrate --settings=core.settings.production                             4.5s
------
 > [6/7] RUN python3 manage.py makemigrate --settings=core.settings.production:
#0 3.964 /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py:158: RuntimeWarning: Got an error checking a consistent migration history performed for database connection 'default': could not translate host name "postgres" to address: Name or service not known
#0 3.964 
#0 3.964   warnings.warn(
#0 3.985 No changes detected in app 'tags'
#0 4.016 No changes detected in app 'users'
#0 4.050 No changes detected in app 'content'
#0 4.081 No changes detected in app 'actions'
#0 4.102 Traceback (most recent call last):
#0 4.102   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 289, in ensure_connection
#0 4.104     self.connect()
#0 4.104   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
#0 4.105     return func(*args, **kwargs)
#0 4.105   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 270, in connect
#0 4.106     self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
#0 4.106   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
#0 4.107     return func(*args, **kwargs)
#0 4.107   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 269, in get_new_connection
#0 4.108     connection = self.Database.connect(**conn_params)
#0 4.108   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
#0 4.109     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
#0 4.109 psycopg2.OperationalError: could not translate host name "postgres" to address: Name or service not known
#0 4.109 
#0 4.109 
#0 4.109 The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
#0 4.109 
#0 4.109 Traceback (most recent call last):
#0 4.109   File "/noted/noted/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
#0 4.110     main()
#0 4.110   File "/noted/noted/manage.py", line 18, in main
#0 4.111     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
#0 4.111   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
#0 4.112     utility.execute()
#0 4.112   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 436, in execute
#0 4.113     self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
#0 4.113   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 412, in run_from_argv
#0 4.115     self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
#0 4.115   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 458, in execute
#0 4.115     output = self.handle(*args, **options)
#0 4.117   File "/noted/noted/common/management/commands/makemigrate.py", line 19, in handle
#0 4.118     call_command("migrate")
#0 4.120   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 194, in call_command
#0 4.120     return command.execute(*args, **defaults)
#0 4.120   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 458, in execute
#0 4.121     output = self.handle(*args, **options)
#0 4.121   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 106, in wrapper
#0 4.121     res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
#0 4.121   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 117, in handle
#0 4.124     executor = MigrationExecutor(connection, self.migration_progress_callback)
#0 4.125   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 18, in __init__
#0 4.128     self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
#0 4.128   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 58, in __init__
#0 4.129     self.build_graph()
#0 4.130   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 235, in build_graph
#0 4.131     self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
#0 4.132   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 81, in applied_migrations
#0 4.132     if self.has_table():
#0 4.134   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 57, in has_table
#0 4.134     with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
#0 4.134   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
#0 4.135     return func(*args, **kwargs)
#0 4.135   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 330, in cursor
#0 4.135     return self._cursor()
#0 4.135   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 306, in _cursor
#0 4.136     self.ensure_connection()
#0 4.136   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
#0 4.136     return func(*args, **kwargs)
#0 4.137   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 288, in ensure_connection
#0 4.138     with self.wrap_database_errors:
#0 4.138   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
#0 4.141     raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
#0 4.142   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 289, in ensure_connection
#0 4.144     self.connect()
#0 4.144   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
#0 4.144     return func(*args, **kwargs)
#0 4.144   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 270, in connect
#0 4.145     self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
#0 4.145   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
#0 4.145     return func(*args, **kwargs)
#0 4.145   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 269, in get_new_connection
#0 4.146     connection = self.Database.connect(**conn_params)
#0 4.146   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
#0 4.146     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
#0 4.146 django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "postgres" to address: Name or service not known
#0 4.146 
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c python3 manage.py makemigrate --settings=core.settings.production" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

This is my Database settings in django

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2",
        "NAME": get_env_variable("DATABASE_NAME"),
        "USER": get_env_variable("DATABASE_USER"),
        "PASSWORD": get_env_variable("DATABASE_PASSWORD"),
        "HOST": get_env_variable("DATABASE_HOST"),
        "PORT": get_env_variable("DATABASE_PORT"),
    }
}
```

This is my dockerfile content

```
FROM python:3.10

WORKDIR /noted

COPY . .

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 

RUN pip install -r requirements/production.txt \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y install wkhtmltopdf \
    && apt-get -y autoclean

EXPOSE 8000

WORKDIR /noted/noted

RUN python3 manage.py makemigrate --settings=core.settings.production

RUN manage.py collectstatic --noinput --settings=core.settings.production

# Set the entry point command for gunicorn
CMD ["gunicorn", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:8000", "core.wsgi"]
```

This is my docker compose content

```
version: '3'
services:
    app:
        build:
            context: .
        container_name: noted_app
        env_file: .env
        volumes:
            - ./noted:/noted
        ports:
          - 8000:8000
        networks:
            - noted-network
        depends_on:
            postgres:
                condition: service_healthy

    postgres:
        image: postgres
        restart: always
        container_name: postgres
        volumes:
            - ./postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
        ports:
            - 5432:5432
        networks:
            - noted-network
        env_file:
            - .env
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=${DATABASE_USER}
            - POSTGRES_DB=${DATABASE_NAME}
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
               
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD-SHELL", "sh -c 'pg_isready -U ${DATABASE_USER} -d ${DATABASE_NAME}'"]
            interval: 10s
            timeout: 3s
            retries: 3

networks:
  noted-network:
```

This is my database variables in my .env file

```
DATABASE_NAME=postgres
DATABASE_USER=postgres
DATABASE_PASSWORD=postgres
DATABASE_HOST=postgres
DATABASE_PORT=5432
```

My docker-compose.yml file and the .env file are in the same location. Please how can I get pass this error .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why the command is like this?

```
python3 manage.py makemigrate
```

It should be

```
python3 manage.py makemigrations
python3 manage.py migrate
```